# Problem with ts-node (typescript) when trying to use files outside the main file | Cannot find module '/home/user/project/src/domain/database'

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I have a problem when trying to use files outside the main file in my TypeScript project using ts-node. When I try to import a file from another file, I get an error saying "Cannot find module". I have checked that the path to the file is correct and that the file exists. Here is my tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

Here is the structure of my project:

```
- src
  - domain
    - database.ts
  - index.ts
- tsconfig.json
- package.json
```

And this is my index.ts and database.ts file:

```js
// index.ts
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import Fastify from 'fastify';
import database from '../src/domain/database';
const fastify = Fastify();

database
  .raw('select 1')
  .then(() =>
    console.log('Connection to database has been established successfully')
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, function (err, address) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log(`Server is now listening on ${address}`);
});

// domain/database.ts

import knex from 'knex';

const database = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  },
  pool: { min: 0, max: 7 },
});

export default database;
```

and in my package.json file I have "type":"module"

my script for run

```json
 "dev": "ts-node --esm src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
```

I also get the problem when I build with typescript

But I get an error saying "Cannot find module '...src/domain/database'". What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it? I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: does one of your imports include the `src` folder in it? all paths should be relative so it will translate correctly to the `dist` folder. also, check the structure of your `dist` folder. does it have the same file structure as your `src` folder?

Comment: yes, I could solve it anyway, I changed the module in the tsconfig.json to common and it works, but I don't know why in esmodules it doesn't do it